# SQL customer-order query with order date ranges

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to get an order report returning not only a customers total number of orders, but also three additional fields, containing dates for first and last order, as well as the range (in days) between first and last order

The following query

```
SELECT customers.name, 
   customers.customer_id, 
   COUNT(orders.order_id) AS Orderscount 
   FROM customers 
   JOIN orders ON customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id 
   GROUP BY customers.name,
            customers.customer_id                       
         HAVING Orderscount >= 2  
         ORDER BY Orderscount DESC
```

returns a table with name, customer_id and the count of total number of orders.

Question is, how can one add to this query to also get the date for the first_order, last_order and the date range between the two?

I'm using SQLite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `MIN` and `MAX` to get first and last order date and `julianday()` to calculate range:

```
SELECT customers.name, 
   customers.customer_id, 
   COUNT(orders.order_id) AS Orderscount,
   MIN(col_name) AS firstOrder,
   MAX(col_name) AS lastOrder,
   ROUND(julianday(MAX(col_name)) - julianday(MIN(col_name))) AS range
FROM customers 
JOIN orders ON customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id 
GROUP BY customers.name,
         customers.customer_id                       
HAVING Orderscount >= 2  
ORDER BY Orderscount DESC
```

Comment: That worked very well. The range came out as a fractional 'day' number. How would I round it to an integer?
(I changed col_name to my purchase_date field)

Comment: @TotteKarlsson Add `ROUND` to round to nearest integer.

Comment: @TotteKarlsson Or `CAST(... AS INT)` to truncate fractional part

Comment: I ended up with ROUND since SQLite don't have ceil.

Comment: @TotteKarlsson Yup, but you can use `CAST`. Please refresh page, probably you've missed my second comment.